# How to select top when already selected fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just wanted to ask how to add a 'select top 1 *' when I've already selected fields from a list? I seen examples in other codes but don't quite get it. Thought will be easier if see it in a code I constructed.

Below is an example of a query I have:

```
select frp.ProductPersonID,frp.FlightSeatId, frp.PlusMealId,  per.TitleID,  per.surname,  per.FirstName, per.PersonTypeId, tor.PersonID, tor.Reference
from package pk 
        inner join product p  on p.packageid = pk.packageid
        inner join productperson pp on pp.productid = p.productid
        inner join person per on per.personid = pp.personid 
        left join flightlogicalseat fls on fls.productpersonid = pp.productpersonid
        inner join TourOperatorReference tor  on tor.PersonID = per.PersonId 
        inner join FlightReservationPassenger frp on frp.ProductPersonID = pp.ProductPersonId
where pk.Reference LIKE '%'
and ProductTypeId =1
```

Comment: `select top 1 frp.ProductPersonID, ....`

Comment: Apart from the `TOP 1` also add an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: It's select top 1 (rows). This has nothing to do with the field list which comes after the top 1 part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try to use [TOP keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) like this:

```
select TOP 1 frp.ProductPersonID,frp.FlightSeatId, frp.PlusMealId,  per.TitleID,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap your existing query in new query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM
(select frp.ProductPersonID,frp.FlightSeatId, frp.PlusMealId,  per.TitleID,  per.surname,  per.FirstName, per.PersonTypeId, tor.PersonID, tor.Reference
from package pk 
        inner join product p  on p.packageid = pk.packageid
        inner join productperson pp on pp.productid = p.productid
        inner join person per on per.personid = pp.personid 
        left join flightlogicalseat fls on fls.productpersonid = pp.productpersonid
        inner join TourOperatorReference tor  on tor.PersonID = per.PersonId 
        inner join FlightReservationPassenger frp on frp.ProductPersonID = pp.ProductPersonId
where pk.Reference LIKE '%'
and ProductTypeId =1) t
```